# CORS Problem in .net core Application - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, cors, jira

I have a CORS problem in my ASP .net core MVC application. My Framework version is .net core 3.1

I want to make a request to our Jira Server, so I need to add CORS. My Startup looks like followed:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)        {
        ...    
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "MyPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://jira.server.com").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials();
                });
        });

    }

public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, AuthorizationDbContext context, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {   
        ...

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


    }
```

My xmlHttpRequest looks like this:

```
    var data = { "fields": { "project": { "key": "projectName" }, "summary": "Test", "description": "Test", "issuetype": { "name": "Bug" }, "fixVersions": [{ "name": "Ideenpool" }] } }

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {

    };
    xhr.open("POST", "https://jira.server.com/api/2/issue", true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://jira.server.com");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));
    xhr.send(data);
```

I alway get the error: 
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://jira.server.com/api/2/issue' from origin 'https://localhost:44301' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I tried to allow all Origins and put a "*" in my request, but always the same error. My curl request in cmd works.

Has anyone an Idea? What am I missing?

Best regards
Sebastian

Comment: You are posting to _Jira's API_, not your API though. Your CORS policies won't affect that.

Comment: https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/cors-error-with-rest-api/27354/4

Comment: That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As per the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#credentials-in-cross-origin-requests), it must be noted that:

> Specifying AllowAnyOrigin and AllowCredentials is an insecure
>   configuration and can result in cross-site request forgery. The CORS
>   service returns an invalid CORS response when an app is configured
>   with both methods.
>   The HTTP response includes an Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header,
>   which tells the browser that the server allows credentials for a
>   cross-origin request.
>
> If the browser sends credentials but the response doesn't include a
>   valid Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header, the browser doesn't
>   expose the response to the app, and the cross-origin request fails.
>
> Allowing cross-origin credentials is a security risk. A website at
>   another domain can send a signed-in user's credentials to the app on
>   the user's behalf without the user's knowledge. The CORS specification
>   also states that setting origins to "*" (all origins) is invalid if
>   the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is present.

If you are specifying `builder.WithOrigins("https://jira.server.com")`, you don't need to specify 'AllowCredentials()'. Take a look at github issues [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19581) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3106)

To get it work, try this code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)        {
        ...    
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(
                "MyPolicy", builder =>
                {
                    builder.WithOrigins("https://jira.server.com").           
                            AllowAnyMethod().
                            AllowAnyHeader();
                          //AllowCredentials();
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still get the same error, when I remove AllowCredentials(). I don't want to use AllowAnyOrigin() either, it was just an attempt.